# Hide element in which data is empty using Angular

Tags: angularjs

[Here is code pen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJvJbW)

Want to hide below element if `x.phone2` is null.

```
<div class="telePhone"  ><strong>Phone2 :</strong> {{x.phone2}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` for that ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)):

```
<div class="telePhone"  ng-if="x.phone2"><strong>Phone2 :</strong> {{x.phone2}}</div>
```

[Updated code pen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYNYKd)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="telePhone" 
     ng-if="x.phone2">
  <strong>Phone2 :</strong> {{x.phone2}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to hide it and don't need two way binding use:

```
<div class="telePhone" ng-if="x.phone"><strong>Phone2 :</strong> {{x.phone2}}</div>
```

If you still need two way binding use:

```
<div class="telePhone" ng-show="x.phone"><strong>Phone2 :</strong> {{x.phone2}}</div>
```

Using ng-if will lower you overhead, but if you need to show the div if the x.phone value changes, you need to use ng-show.